# How to hide Rails auto generated flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am using this to show flash messages in rails

```
  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
      <h3>Error!</h3>
      <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <ul>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    </ul>
<%end%>
```

rails is also showing its generated flashes like

```
["Description is too short (minimum is 20 characters)"]
```

on the index page also

Comment: Do you want to change the format they're being rendered or not to show them?

Comment: I want to remove the flash generated by rails.And keep only one.

Comment: I would recommend you to use the flash and put the errors of the models in there. Then you can use one standardized way to display errors to the user

Answer (score 1):

In my local env,

```
flash.clear
```

works well.

Comment: Sorry,but I am a real noob,where is local env?

Comment: local env means that "Enviroment of Local(My) Computer".

Answer (score 0):

From the rails docs:

You can use

```
flash.discard 
flash.discard(:error)
```

To mark the entire flash or a single flash entry to be discarded by the end of the current action:

Or use

```
flash.clear
```

You can find all the methods exposed by rails [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html).